# Kotlin - Google Photos API integration

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, google-photos, google-photos-api

How can I integrate Google Photos API into my Android app using Kotlin to get the list of Albums and image according to album id.

I have tried so many ways and solution given on internet but i couldn't find proper documentation or any sample which can guide me.

Can anyone of you help me out to solve this or integrate Google Photos API.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started

Comment: @c-an yes i have checked this but i can not configure what to add in this below mentioned field...  FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. */))